# iterated value does not shown correctly in nested for loop using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The output shown:

```
421.279
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
0
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
0
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Desired output is

```
421.279
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
851.319
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
421.279
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Here is the script:

```
import numpy as np
x = [0.000, 421.279, 851.319, 421.279, 0.000, -421.279, -851.319]

m = 3

for i in np.arange(1, m+1):
    a = x[i] 
    print(a)
    for (i, item) in enumerate(x):
        if item == a:
            x[i] = 1
        else:
            x[i] = 0 
               
    y = x 
    print(y)
```

Comment: You are writing 0 or 1 values into `x`. Why do you expect that `x` still contains the original values after the first iteration of the outer loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script does what you requested:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0.000, 421.279, 851.319, 421.279, 0.000, -421.279, -851.319])

for i in range(1,4):
    print(x[i], np.where(x == x[i], 1, 0))
```

Comment: Excellent!. I like your two lines codes. Thanks

Comment: if adding another y array  similar x array and add another argument into print.  As "y = np.array" and replace "print(x[i], np.where(x == x[i], 1, 0))" with "print(x[i], np.where(x == x[i], 1, 0), y[(np.where(x == x[i], 1, 0))])". Why the output of the third row do not show [0. 0. 851.319 0. 0. 0. 0.] instead of [0. 0. 421.279 0. 0. 0. 0.]

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `x` in the first iteration with `0` and `1`.
Small tweak to get the desired results:

```py
import numpy as np
x = [0.000, 421.279, 851.319, 421.279, 0.000, -421.279, -851.319]

m = 3

for i in np.arange(1, m+1):
    a = x[i] 
    print(a)
    y = [0] * len(x)
    for (i, item) in enumerate(x):
        if item == a:
            y[i] = 1
        else:
            y[i] = 0 
               
    print(y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `x[i] = 1` and `x[i] = 0`, you're modifying the `x` array, which you shouldn't
Solution is very easy, you use another array *(in this case y)* to assign the solution values and the work should be done

```
import numpy as np
x = [0.000, 421.279, 851.319, 421.279, 0.000, -421.279, -851.319]

m = 3

for i in np.arange(1, m+1):
    a = x[i] 
    print(a)
    for (i, item) in enumerate(x):
        if item == a:
            y[i] = 1
        else:
            y[i] = 0 
               
    
    print(y)
```

Result is as expected:

```
421.279
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
851.319
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
421.279
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: y[i] needs to  define or it will not work. Thanks for mention about my code will modify the original array.